# Generate moving average for stackedbarchart in JFreeChart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, bar-chart, moving-average

I would like to generate a chart which combines both stackedbarchart and a moving average line in the same chart.

I am currently using a DefaultCategoryDataset object for my stackedBarChart, and am unsure how I can use the data I am passing into this to generate a moving average line as well.

I have read the [online documentation](http://jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html) for JFreeChart, which discusses moving average on page 749. However, I am unable to determine how to implement it in my code using the current DefaultCategoryDataset.

What would be an effective way to accomplish the objective?

Comment: That's not "the online documentation for JFreeChart", it is a link to a site that is redistributing the JFreeChart Developer Guide PDF without permission (that is, illegally).  The JFreeChart project is funded by selling this guide along with source code for the 150+ JFreeChart demo programs - see http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html for details.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting David, I will update the link in my post. JFreeChart is a good project, I wasn't aware the documentation was not supposed to be free til now.

Comment: Done, now that we have the legality section handled, I hope someone can help with my question

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.